# I want to form a m x n matrix by giving some numbers as input in c#

Tags: c#

HI,

suppose i have given input numbers like this 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0

i should form it as 3 x 3 matrix but my input has 10 elements how to form a matrix 
for such input in c#

Comment: you can't fit 10 numbers in a 3x3 matrix. :-)

Comment: I should have read the question more carefully. Now I understand the problem. You need to make `3 x 3 = 10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
int[] arr = new int[3 + 1/3, 3]
```

Comment: You solved the easy part, the hard part is splitting the last integer.

Comment: @Rob Elliott: one third of it goes into each of three bins. :)

Answer (score 1):

How do you fit ten elements into nine variables? You don't.

You're asking an impossible question. I'm sure someone will come up with some absurd hack that lets you do this, but that doesn't make it sensible to store data this way.

Use a larger array, or store fewer values.